# Meter en una lista la info de una BBDD

Tags: java, android-studio

Estoy haciendo un curso de Android y ando un poco perdido. Dado que como el tiempo se me hecha encima, me veo obligado a pedir ayuda por aquí, en lugar de investigar durante varias semanas más. Espero que mi sinceridad les haga comprender mis preguntas.

1º/ de muchas ;-)

Tengo una clase para acceder a una BBDD, sacar su contenido y pasarlo a una lista. Esta lista se pasará a un Adaptador y se mostrará por un RecicleView. Mi objetivo es que se pueda mostrar los diferentes campos de la BBDD ( _id, nombre, apellidos) por separado en c/u de los Recicleview. Pero que me permita obtener el _id de cada uno para hacer modificaciones/eliminaciones en la BBDD según el id.

Ahora mismo lo que he conseguido es esto. La lista tiene un String que contiene el id+nombre+apellidos. Me gustaría acceder por separado a esos valores.

[image: pantallazo del RecicleView]

Cuando pasa el registro del RecicleView a la siguiente Activity, pasa la linea completa y no puedo obtener el id para rellenar el resto de campos.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El código de la clase bbdd:

```
 @Override
    public ArrayList<String> listaUsuarios(int cantidad) {
        ArrayList<String> result = new ArrayList<String>();
        SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();

        // metodo query()
        String[] CAMPOS = {"_id","nombre", "apellidos"};
        Cursor cursor=db.query("usuarios", CAMPOS, null, null,
                null, null, "_id  ", null);

        while (cursor.moveToNext()){
            //todo en una sola linea
            result.add(cursor.getInt(0)+" " +cursor.getString(1)+" "+cursor.getString(2));
             //result.add(cursor.getInt(0),cursor.getString(1), cursor.getString(2)); -->da error

        }
        cursor.close();
        db.close();
        return result;
    }
```

El código del Adaptador:

```
    @Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int i) {
    //mostrar cada elemento de la lista
    holder.titulo.setText(lista.get(i));
    //holder.subtitutlo.setText(lista.get(i).indexOf(2));
    //holder.id.setText(lista.indexOf(i));
    //determinar eventos para los botones
    holder.setOnClickListeners();
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return lista.size();
}


public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
    public TextView titulo, subtitutlo;
    public TextView id;
    public Button Bmodify;
    public Button Beliminar;
     Context context;
    ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        //Obteniendo referencia Context
        context=itemView.getContext();
        subtitutlo=itemView.findViewById(R.id.subtitulo);
        titulo = itemView.findViewById(R.id.titulo);
        Bmodify= itemView.findViewById(R.id.modificar);
        Beliminar = itemView.findViewById(R.id.eliminar);
        id = itemView.findViewById(R.id.id);
    }
```

Espero haberme explicado con claridad. Pero de no ser así, díganme que más necesitan saber.

Saludos cordiales

Comment: Porqué en vez de sumar los datos de la base de datos en un String, no creas un ArrayList de objetos de una clase que te hagas tuya con su id, nombre y apellidos, como variables separadas? Tu función listaUsuarios retornaría un ArrayList<Usuario> que es la que guardarías en el adaptador. Y luego en el adaptador, le metes el contenido a cada TextView.

Comment: Gracias @SuperG280. Efectivamente, me pase la noche haciendo eso que dices y he conseguido que el efecto deseado. 
Ahora toca pasar los valores desde el recicleView a la Actividad  para modificar o eliminar el registro ... me esta constando más de lo pensado.
Muchas gracias de nuevo.

Comment: Como la lista con los datos está en el adapter, sabiendo la posición del elemento a modificar o borrar, desde la activity puedes acceder al objeto del adapter,modificar lo que necesites y forzar el repintado de toda la lista ejecutando notifydatasetchanged